# sql server trigger to update another database whenever a sproc is created

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, triggers

Is there a way to update another database with the newly created stored procedure whenever a stored procedure is created in the main database?

For example, i have two databases, DB1 and DB2.

When I create a stored procedure in DB1, i want that same procedure to created in DB2 automatically? Is there a trigger that can do this?

```
 USE [DB1]
   CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestSproc]
        ..something

    AS
    BEGIN
        ...something 

    END
```

I know a use [DB2] statement will do the job, but i want this to be done automatically. Any thought?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does it have to happen immediately? You could do this with a job.

Comment: @JChao maybe a silly question but again they say no question is silly :).... A job to do what?

Comment: Think carefully about whether you want to do this. Triggers run within the context of the original transaction. If `DB2` is temporarily unavailable, do you want that fact to *prevent* you from creating objects in `DB1`? Usually, the answer to this is no which is why usually, the advice is that triggers shouldn't access anything outside of their own database.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a bit evil, but in SQL Server you are able to create DDL triggers which fire when you create/alter/drop tables/procedures etc. The syntax to fire when a procedure is created is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER <proc-name>
ON DATABASE
FOR CREATE_PROCEDURE
AS

--Your code goes here
```

In a DDL trigger you get access to an object called EVENTDATA. So to get the text of the procedure you created:

```
SELECT EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand/CommandText)[1]','nvarchar(max)')
```

Now all you need to do is keep that value and execute it in your secondary database. So your query becomes something like this, though I leave the code to update the secondary database down to you as I don't know if it's on the same server, linked server etc.:

```
CREATE TRIGGER sproc_copy
ON DATABASE
FOR CREATE_PROCEDURE
AS

DECLARE @procedureDDL AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand/CommandText)[1]','nvarchar(max)')

--Do something with @procedureDDL
```

As this is not tested, there's probably a few gotchas. For example, what happens if you create procedure with full name (`CREATE PROC server.database.schema.proc`)

Comment: Cheers Dave, I knew there was a DDL Trigger with event CREATE_PROCEDURE but didnt know how to get the DDL text/query for actual event which triggered the trigger. will look into this. :) + 1 for teaching me something new :)

Comment: @M.Ali Haha I just happened to come across this a few months ago, I still think it's a bit evil though and prefer using DDL triggers for auditing, security etc.

Comment: Yes I have used DDL trigger to prevent unintentional Table/Database drops but have never done this kind of thing with DDL trigger, just shows you how much there is to learn :)

Answer (score 0):

No simple solution for this unless you want to execute the same statement twice, once on each target database,

One thing that comes to my mind is that you can Set up Replication and only publish Stored Procedures to your second database which will be the subscriber in this case.

Following is the window where you select which Objects you want to send over to your secondary databases.

[image]

Comment: where do you find the publication wizard? i couldn't find it in my sql server. Not sure if this is due to permission issue.